# Simple HTML DOM str_replace on plain text

Tags: php, mysql, dom, str-replace, simple-html-dom

I am trying to create something where it will change all of the text on a webpage and re output it to the user. It will be changing words predefined in a database.

I am using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net as my HTML parser. What i want todo is to change only the test inside of tags but not the tags. I thought this would work, If i echo out `$e->plaintext` it will work but then it isn't styled.

```
<?php
// example of how to modify HTML contents
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/');

$e = $html->find("html", 0);

$text = $e->plaintext;

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","Words");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Wordsweb");

//replace all words
$English = array();
$Simple = array();

while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $English[] = $row['English'];
    $Simple[] = $row['Simple'];
}

$e->plaintext = str_replace($English, $Simple,$e->plaintext);
echo $e;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

*p.s.*: previously i was using `preg_replace_callback` but i was advised to use this.

Comment: It will be hard to find what's wrong without checking the actual code you're replacing... To start, try `$e->innertext` instead... If it still not working, post at least the part of the html code you're working on...

Comment: Have a look at [simple html dom and text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10146631).

Comment: @Enissay I have tried $e->innertext and still no hope. If i echo $e->plaintext it shows my updates but doesn't if i want to show them with the tags to style it!

Comment: Did you try `$e->outertext`... It shows nodes content including the surrouding tags

Comment: @Enissay It echoes the page but not with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the contents of each text node individually, rather than changing the text of the whole file at once:

```
<?php

// load the HTML document
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana');

// select all the text nodes
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//text()');

// replace text in each text node
$english = array('banana', 'bananas');
$simple = array('yello', 'yellos');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = str_replace($english, $simple, $node->nodeValue);
}

print $doc->saveHTML();
```